# PHP Switch not outputting.

Tags: php

I have this code that takes the value from another variable that it gets from an XML file. This currently worked before I cleaned up the code and now I don't know why it's not working. How it's suppose to work is takes the variable and creates a color based on the value of that variable. Then I take that new variable in this case $stormScale and assign it to a CSS class to display that color for the cell like so.

```
$td4Style = "{$sbrdr}; {$bbrdr}; padding: 2px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:{$stormScale};";
```

Then I take that class and use it when the table for the other data is outputted like so.

```
$tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td4Style}'>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n";
```

This switch is suppose to assign the colors based on the value but it's not working now and I am not sure why or what I am missing.

```
$stormScale = '';

           switch($ef)
{
              case '0':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '1':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)';
                             break;
              case '2':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '3':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)';
                             break;
              case '4':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '5':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)';
                             break;

}
```

Here is the complete code. I hope I have provided enough information. What am I missing?

```
<?php 
#######################################################################################
#
#  GOOGLE MAPS V3 KILLER TORNADOS
#  version 1.00
#
#  This program is free and no license is required.
#  
#
#  mesquiteweather.net
#
#######################################################################################

////  SETTINGS  ////

$GKey = 'ENTER_YOUR_KEY';                    // Enter your Google Maps API Key
$GImage = 'images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';     // Path to your watermark for your Google Map

// Change colors
$bc        = 'True';     // If True cell tables will show color of EF scale, set to false to use CSS style color
$dtColor   = '#FFF';     // Ttile Color  Examples:   "#FC0"   "#FFCC00"   "white"

////  END OF SETTINGS  ////

#######################################################################################

ini_set('display_errors','1');

// overrides from the Carter Lake Settings.php file (if applicable)
global $SITE;
if(isset($SITE['cacheFileDir'])) {$cacheFileDir = $SITE['cacheFileDir']; }
if (isset($SITE['imagesDir']))   {$imagesDir = $SITE['imagesDir'];}
if(isset ($SITE['tz']))          {$ourTZ = $SITE['tz'];}
if(!function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    putenv("TZ=" . $ourTZ);
}
else
{
    date_default_timezone_set("$ourTZ");
}

// get path info & protect for cross-site scripting vulnerability
$sri = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? str_replace('#SA', '', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) : '';

//Set path to data file
$data = "http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/torn/xml/2013.xml";

$bbrdr = 'border-bottom:thin solid black';       // bottom
$lbrdr = 'border-left:thin solid black';         // left
$rbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black';        // right
$tbrdr = 'border-top:thin solid black';          // top
$sbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black; '.
         'border-left:thin solid black';         // side
$tableStyle = "width: 100%; margin:0px auto; background-color:{$bkgColor};";
$td1Style = "{$tbrdr};{$sbrdr}; padding:2px 0px 2px 6px;  background-image:url({$imagesDir}headerbgd2.gif); color:{$dtColor};";
$td2Style = "{$sbrdr}; padding:6px 0px 0px 6px; background-color:{$stormScale};";
$td3Style = "{$sbrdr}; line-height:5px; background-color:{$stormScale};";
$td4Style = "{$sbrdr}; {$bbrdr}; padding: 2px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:{$stormScale};";

//Define table to display after each storm report
$afterTable = "<table style='margin-bottom: 10px;' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody><tr><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td class='shadow-mid' width='100%'><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td></tr><tbody></table>\n";


// Lets parse the XML feed
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);

//Set initial output to false
    $tData = false;
foreach($xml->fatalities as $fatalities){

    $yrnum = $fatalities['yrnum'];
    $dt = $fatalities['dt'];
    $time = $fatalities['time'];
    $updateTime = DATE("g:i a", STRTOTIME($time));
    $tz = $fatalities['tz'];
    $ef = $fatalities['ef'];
    $location = $fatalities['location'];
    $state = $fatalities['st'];
    $watch = $fatalities['watch'];
    $watchn = str_replace("WT","WW","$watch");
    $deaths = $fatalities['deaths'];

  $stormScale = '';

           switch($ef)
{
              case '0':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '1':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)';
                             break;
              case '2':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '3':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)';
                             break;
              case '4':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 0.2)';
                             break;
              case '5':
                    $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)';
                             break;

}



 // construct data for table display
    $tData .= "<table style='{$tableStyle}' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>\n";
    $tData .= "<tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td1Style}'><b>2013 Killer Tornado #{$yrnum}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr>\n";
    $tData .= "    <td style='{$td2Style}'>Date: <b>{$dt}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Time: <b>{$updateTime}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>EF: <b>{$ef}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</             b>Fatalities: <b>{$deaths}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;Watch Issued: {$watchn}<b></a></td>\n";
    $tData .= "  </tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td3Style}'>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td4Style}'>County: <b>{$location}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;State: <b>{$state}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "</tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "</table>\n";
    $tData .=  $afterTable;

 }  

?>

<?php print $tData ?>
```

-Thanks

Comment: Why not just use classes and style the CSS _in CSS_?

Comment: Where you are using ` $stormScale` in table display? I couldn't find it in you pasted code here.

Comment: @elclanrs 1. The cells colors are not static, they're dynamically created based on the value of the data then assigned to the table. 2. This is a script I am developing that is an add on for a template set that will be shared with other people. So it needs to be pretty much plug and play with not a lot of set up. Upload and go. 3. Using inline styles allows for this since the styles will not be global and would just add unnecessary styles to the CSS for just one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning variable before its creation. change your script like this

```
<?php 
#######################################################################################
#
#  GOOGLE MAPS V3 KILLER TORNADOS
#  version 1.00
#
#  This program is free and no license is required.
#  
#
#  mesquiteweather.net
#
#######################################################################################

////  SETTINGS  ////

$GKey = 'ENTER_YOUR_KEY';                    // Enter your Google Maps API Key
$GImage = 'images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';     // Path to your watermark for your Google Map

// Change colors
$bc        = 'True';     // If True cell tables will show color of EF scale, set to false to use CSS style color
$dtColor   = '#FFF';     // Ttile Color  Examples:   "#FC0"   "#FFCC00"   "white"

////  END OF SETTINGS  ////

#######################################################################################

ini_set('display_errors','1');

// overrides from the Carter Lake Settings.php file (if applicable)
global $SITE;
if(isset($SITE['cacheFileDir'])) {$cacheFileDir = $SITE['cacheFileDir']; }
if (isset($SITE['imagesDir']))   {$imagesDir = $SITE['imagesDir'];}
if(isset ($SITE['tz']))          {$ourTZ = $SITE['tz'];}
if(!function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    putenv("TZ=" . $ourTZ);
}
else
{
    date_default_timezone_set("$ourTZ");
}

// get path info & protect for cross-site scripting vulnerability
$sri = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? str_replace('#SA', '', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) : '';

//Set path to data file
$data = "http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/torn/xml/2013.xml";

$bbrdr = 'border-bottom:thin solid black';       // bottom
$lbrdr = 'border-left:thin solid black';         // left
$rbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black';        // right
$tbrdr = 'border-top:thin solid black';          // top
$sbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black; '.
         'border-left:thin solid black';         // side
$tableStyle = "width: 100%; margin:0px auto; background-color:{$bkgColor};";

//Define table to display after each storm report
$afterTable = "<table style='margin-bottom: 10px;' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody><tr><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td class='shadow-mid' width='100%'><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td></tr><tbody></table>\n";


// Lets parse the XML feed
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);

//Set initial output to false
    $tData = false;
foreach($xml->fatalities as $fatalities){

    $yrnum = $fatalities['yrnum'];
    $dt = $fatalities['dt'];
    $time = $fatalities['time'];
    $updateTime = DATE("g:i a", STRTOTIME($time));
    $tz = $fatalities['tz'];
    $ef = $fatalities['ef'];
    $location = $fatalities['location'];
    $state = $fatalities['st'];
    $watch = $fatalities['watch'];
    $watchn = str_replace("WT","WW","$watch");
    $deaths = $fatalities['deaths'];

  $stormScale = '';

       switch($ef)
    {
          case '0':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)';
                 break;
          case '1':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)';
                 break;
          case '2':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)';
                 break;
          case '3':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)';
                 break;
          case '4':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 0.2)';
                 break;
          case '5':
            $stormScale = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)';
                 break;

    }
$td1Style = "{$tbrdr};{$sbrdr}; padding:2px 0px 2px 6px;  background-image:url({$imagesDir}headerbgd2.gif); color:{$dtColor};";
$td2Style = "{$sbrdr}; padding:6px 0px 0px 6px; background-color:{$stormScale};";
$td3Style = "{$sbrdr}; line-height:5px; background-color:{$stormScale};";
$td4Style = "{$sbrdr}; {$bbrdr}; padding: 2px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:{$stormScale};";


 // construct data for table display
    $tData .= "<table style='{$tableStyle}' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>\n";
    $tData .= "<tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td1Style}'><b>2013 Killer Tornado #{$yrnum}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr>\n";
    $tData .= "    <td style='{$td2Style}'>Date: <b>{$dt}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Time: <b>{$updateTime}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>EF: <b>{$ef}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</             b>Fatalities: <b>{$deaths}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;Watch Issued: {$watchn}<b></a></td>\n";
    $tData .= "  </tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td3Style}'>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td4Style}'>County: <b>{$location}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;State: <b>{$state}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "</tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "</table>\n";
    $tData .=  $afterTable;

 }  

?>

<?php print $tData ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

During a run what is the values of $ef. Might help to to throw a

```
default:
    print_r($fatalities);
    die("unhandled ef value ".$ef); 
    break;
```

into the switch statement to shed a little more light

More likely then not simplexml is giving you an array or something you aren't expecting for the $ef value. Also with simplexml it's always a good idea to do an explicit cast for returned data. ie `switch ((string)$ef)`